# How to implement swipe function in one of the Fragment tab? **Not TAB+SWIPE**

Tags: android, android-fragments

**I'm very new to Android environment and hence this question may be simple to some of you. Please try not to be too harsh on me. Thanks.**

Following the tutorial on this site: http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/761642-android-app-development-for-beginners-navigation-with-tabs , I've successfully created an app, having three tabs that having it's own `layout`.

Then I found another tutorial which is about `ViewPager`: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-viewpager-gallery-images-and-texts-tutorial/

I'm trying to combine this two application to become one, which means to place the `ViewPager` into my **tab3**.

As shown on the link, **tab3** need to `setTabListener` and expecting a Fragment class as below:

```
ActionBar.Tab tab3;
Fragment fragmentTab3 = new FragmentTab3();

ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


tab3.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentTab3));
actionBar.addTab(tab3);
```

I'm totally running out of clue on how to modify the code so that it accept a class that extends `PagerAdapter` and allow **tab3** to perform as a `ViewPager`

Comment: do you want also to swipe between other tabs for example do you want to swipe from 1 to 2 ? and also do you want to swipe in tab3 from which page to page? is any dummy page ok?

Comment: @mmlooloo: I don't need to swipe between TABs. I only want to swipe some dummy pages in tab3

Comment: @Mr.SuicideSheep: Kindly check my answer below. The implementation I have suggested would not swipe between tabs but you would be able to swipe the pages in tab 3. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have built a similar application where all the three tabs have viewpagers inside them.

The tab implementation is same as you mentioned:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_file)
            .setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_music)
            .setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_video)
            .setTabListener(this));
```

Assign fragments to individual tabs like this:

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    Fragment mFragment;
    Log.d(TAG, "Inside on tab selected");
    switch (tab.getPosition()) {
    case 0:
        mFragment = Fragment1.newInstance(null);
        ft.replace(R.id.content, mFragment, "fragment1");
        break;

    case 1:
        mFragment = Fragment2.newInstance();
        ft.replace(R.id.content, mFragment, "fragment2");
        break;

    case 2:
        mFragment = Fragment3.newInstance();
        ft.replace(R.id.content, mFragment, "fragment3");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Now fragment3 need not be extend pageradapter. Inside layout for 3rd fragment, add a viewpager

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment_music_root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
tools:context="com.gridants.cubeit.ui.MusicFragment" >
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
            android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="#33b5e5"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</FrameLayout>
```

Inside your fragment3 code, declare the viewpager and your custom fragmentStatePagerAdapter

```
    mDemoCollectionPagerAdapter = new DemoCollectionPagerAdapter(
            getChildFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mDemoCollectionPagerAdapter);
```

Here is sample code for implementation of custom adapter

```
    public class DemoCollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    public Fragment mFragmentAtPos0;
    private Context context;

    public DemoCollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mFragmentManager = fm;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment mFragment;
        Bundle args;
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside on tab selected");
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            mFragment = new InnerFragment1();
            break;

        case 1:
            mFragment = new InnerFragment2();
            break;

        case 2:
            mFragment = new InnerFragment3();
            break;
        }
        return mFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String title;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            title = "OBJECT " + (position + 1);
            break;

        case 1:
            title = "OBJECT " + (position + 1);
            break;

        default:
            title = "OBJECT " + (position + 1);
            break;
        }
        return title;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This code may help u..

```
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), ActionBarActivity.this));
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(i);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {
        }
    });

    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab();
    tab1.setText("Client");
    tab1.setTabListener(this);

    ActionBar.Tab tab2 = actionBar.newTab();
    tab2.setText("Supplier");
    tab2.setTabListener(this);

    ActionBar.Tab tab3 = actionBar.newTab();
    tab3.setText("Driver");
    tab3.setTabListener(this);

    ActionBar.Tab tab4 = actionBar.newTab();
    tab4.setText("Owner");
    tab4.setTabListener(this);

    actionBar.addTab(tab1);
    actionBar.addTab(tab2);
    actionBar.addTab(tab3);
    actionBar.addTab(tab4);
}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

Context context;
public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, Context context){
    super(fragmentManager);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {

    Fragment fragment = null;
    if(i == 0){
        fragment = new FragmentClass1(context);
    }else if(i == 1) {
        fragment = new FragmentClass2(context);
    }else if(i == 2){
        fragment = new FragmentClass3(context);
    }else {
        fragment = new FragmentClass4(context);
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 4;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this code will helps you

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);      
TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),itemsList);
                        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);                          
                        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {                              
                            @Override
                            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float arg1, int arg2) {
                                pos = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
                                //System.out.println("On Page Scrolled :: " +position + " ### :" + arg2);
                                //System.out.println("On Page Scrolled :: pos : "+pos);                                 
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

                            }
                        });
```